# Set the same value to columns if column is null and another value if column is not null using just nvl, decode or coalesce in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, decode, coalesce, nvl

I need write select script that checks if column is null then shows "is null" value, when column is not null then shows "is not null" value in output. But I should use only nvl, decode or coalesce functions. Using another functionalities is not allowed.

Comment: Please, show your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it. These functions are [well-documented with examples](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DECODE.html#GUID-39341D91-3442-4730-BD34-D3CF5D4701CE). StackOverflow is not a codewriting service.

Answer (score 0):

`Decode` is quite simple:

```
select decode(column_name, null, 'is null',
                                 'is not null'
             ) as result
from your_table
```

I don't see why (or how) should `NVL` and `coalesce` be involved here, their purpose is *different*. Maybe you could use them, but - that would be unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I guess this was just homework and unfortunately, you just did it for him/her which is the opposite of homework's idea ;)